# How to use Espresso + JMockit

Tags: java, android, jmockit, android-espresso

I want to use [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/) and [JMockito](http://jmockit.org/).

But I don't run test.
If you have resolve way, help me.

I wrote some file(build.gradle(app, project), Test java) as follows.

---

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "burning.tutorial"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // App's dependencies, including test
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'

    // JMockit
    androidTestCompile 'org.jmockit:jmockit:1.18'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'

}
```

build.gradle(Project)

```
projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

MainActivityTest.java

```
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.age)).check(matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

When this test run, happen error as follows.

```
:app:preDexDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebugAndroidTest
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/junit/runner/Runner;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

you cannot easily fix this, because `JMockit` has a faulty `JUnit` dependency. To fix it, you need to fix `JMockit` first.

**Long answer:**

Your app contains `org.junit.runner.Runner` twice:

- through `JMockit` because it includes the Runner class file in the library (which is bad because it only includes the Runner class and not the whole library).
- through `com.android.support.test:runner` because one of its dependencies is the `junit` library (which is the proper way to add `JUnit` support.

A normal fix would be to exclude one of the following:

- exclude the `JUnit` dependency for `JMockit`:
  This doesn't work, because `JUnit` is not defined as a proper dependency. `JUnit` merely pasted in the class file in its own project. This is a bad thing to do.
- exclude the `JUnit` dependency for `com.android.support.test:runner`:
  We can do this, but this will cut out all the other classes from the junit library that `JMockit` did not put in their project. This will effectively break any other junit code you use.

If you really NEED to use `JMockit` then you could consider to edit the project so it includes the `junit` dependency properly and then recompile it and add it to your project this way.

This shows the faulty dependency:

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

You can see how the `Runner` class is just pasted into the project.

After fixing the `JMockit` dependencies you need to add `JMockit` as follows:

```
androidTestCompile ('org.jmockit:jmockit:1.18') {
    exclude group: 'junit'
}
```

Comment: The `org.junit.runner.Runner` included in JMockit is actually a _modified_ version of the original. It contains the following extra code: `static { Startup.initializeIfPossible(); }`, which I suppose you should now call yourself after doing this modification. I have not yet checked what the deal is with the `sun.tools.attach` package, but I guess it's something similar.